# Create Bitmap from RelativeLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, printing, bitmap

I have a RelativeLayout and wanna create a Bitmap from that and send to bluetooth printer in bytes.
According device resolution, when my bitmap is generate changes textviews fontsize - higher the resolution, higher the fontsize.
How can I generate only one size regardless of device resolution?

My Code:

```
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(580, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(layout.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
layout.layout(0, 0, layout.getMeasuredWidth(), layout.getMeasuredHeight());
layout.buildDrawingCache(false);
Bitmap sImagem = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache(false));
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

580 is the size of my paper and that is ok in printer!

Answer (score 1):

try out this

```
      private void takeScreenShot(){
         int totalHeight = mScreenshotLayout.getHeight();
         int totalWidth  = mScreenshotLayout.getWidth();

         Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(mScreenshotLayout,totalHeight,totalWidth);
         SendingMail(b);

      }

      public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {
      Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth,totalHeight ,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
      Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
      if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
     else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
     view.draw(canvas);
     return returnedBitmap;
}
```